# Getting Past VBA Error when selecting

Tags: vba, excel

I wonder if anybody can help me. I have a macro which selects sheets that are named as employees and puts them into the correct workbook dependant on where they work.

I have made the macro so that it selects all sheets for the depot then copies them into a new workbook.

My problem is when it can't find one of the sheets it skips all of them for that location workbook. and moves to the next location. Is there a way round this so if the macro can't find one of the sheets it moves the rest of them anyway.

```
Sub BIR()
    On Error GoTo Getout
    Sheets(Array("Martyn Arthur Lewis", "Norman Stewart Gray")).Move
    Sheets.Select
    For Each ws In Worksheets
       ws.Activate
       With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
          .PrintHeadings = False
          .PrintGridlines = False
          .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
          .Orientation = xlLandscape
          .Draft = False
          .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
          .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
          .Order = xlDownThenOver
          .BlackAndWhite = False
          .Zoom = 90
          .printerrors = xlPrintErrorsBlank
          .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
          .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
          .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
          .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = False
       End With
    Next
    ChDir "\\afi-uplift\documents\company\Support Services\Support Services Level 1\Reports\Transport Reports\Vehicle KPI"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="\\afi-uplift\documents\company\Support Services\Support Services Level 2\Support Services\Transport\Drivers\Driver Performance\BIR Driver KPI " & Format(Date, "yyyy.mm.dd") & ".xlsx" _
    , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
           Windows("Driver Report.xlsm").Activate
  Getout:
End Sub
```

Comment: please post some code :)

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you want to achieve. Can you clarify - also as to where exactly the code doesn't work as you expect?

Comment: You need to loop through your array and test whether each sheet exists: if it does then Select it: you can add further sheets to the selection using (eg) `Sheets("Name2").Select False` - `False` indicates to add to the already-selected sheet(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why people always need to use .select and .activate
First it slows the program, and second, usualy, you don't even need to select/activate.

Doesn't your code work if you write it like this :

```
option explicit 'forces user to dim variables, , alot easier to find errors

err.clear
on error goto 0 'how can you debug errors with a on error goto (or on error resume next) ?

dim ws as worksheet    

For Each ws In Sheets(Array("Martyn Arthur Lewis", "Norman Stewart Gray"))
   With ws.PageSetup
       'your code
   end with
next ws
```